# Kubernetes services within cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to set up a conventional web app with a database in Kubernetes. I have accomplished it by configuring 2 services and 2 deployments - one for the app and one for the database. Now I would like to make my database accessible only from the app pods, ie not expose it to outside world like a service. Is it possible using only Kubernetes configuration?

Comment: Hi, as you are using deployment for database, and service `type=clusterIP` then It is not exposed. In order to expose a deployment or pod, the service needs to be either `type=NodePort` or  `type=LoadBalancer`.

Comment: @SureshVishnoi changing corresponding service yaml from type: LoadBalancer to type: ClusterIP worked. Can you submit your comment as an answer please?

Comment: Glad, it worked. I have answered the question. I have added another option which is headless-service which might be interested for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following ways to expose the pods.

purpose is inter-service communication

**Internally expose**

- service `type=clusterIP`
- **Headless-service** `clusterIP: None` is used for database pods

> Sometimes you don’t need or want load-balancing and a single service IP. [headless-services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services)

**Externally expose**
 Exposing service to the customers.

- service `type=NodePort`  or `type=LoadBalancer`